# Does anyone use index.html?

Tags: php, html, naming-conventions

As a matter of precaution i always, now, name my index page: index.php, I do this whatever the project. Does anyone use index.html regularly? Can you be concretely sure you'll never need PHP for the page? Are there any performance issues encountered by always using index.php over index.html?

Comment: I can be pretty sure that I'll never need PHP for a page … it is quite a long way down my list of preferred languages.

Comment: If you are using AJAX only for communicating with server-side scripts, you have no problems to name the file index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For servers that don't support PHP, avoid the .php extension unless you are trying to mask the server technology by faking a .php extension.

For static sites it doesn't really matter which extension you use as long as you know your server is configured correctly (see Dominic Rodger's answer). For that matter, not many of your visitors will care whether it's a static or dynamic site. Also, some dynamic sites accept URLs that end in .html as opposed to .php.

> Are there any performance issues encountered by always using index.php over index.html?

The PHP interpreter will immediately hand your output back to your web server if there is absolutely no PHP code in it (all it does is send some engine-specific headers), so the performance difference is negligible if at all existent.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `index.html`, and then if you decide you need PHP, create an `index.php`, and change your [`DirectoryIndex` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) (if you're using Apache).

Comment: What if you're using shared hosting - this may not be an option?

Comment: @benhowdle - basically, use `index.html` until you know you need to use PHP.

Comment: If your hosting is so poor it won't let you twiddle DirectoryIndex, then it isn't good enough.

Comment: Then you should delete the index.html file. Don't you know what file extensions are for?

Comment: Thanks Merjin, constructive comment *sarcasm* i was more on about hyperlinks, menus, sitemaps. A hassle more than anything

Comment: @Merijn — on the web? Nothing at all. URLs don't have file extensions. They are a convenient way to determine what a webserver should do to a file before serving it up, but not the only way.

Comment: @benhowdle89 - you don't need to change the URL for the `DirectoryIndex`, since you can just refer to it using `http://www.example.com/`.

Comment: @Merijn File extensions are unimportant in everything except local file access on Microsoft Windows. They can be helpful if a person wants to visually determine the file type by its name, but on the internet it's actually good practice to _hide_ the scripting language you're using because what matters is the resource, not the format, and not hiding server-side format makes a security breach easier. The browser uses MIME type to determine encoding; it doesn't care about extension. If you must use file extensions, always match MIME type. Read up on HTTP if that is confusing to you.

Comment: @Merijn Although, to be clear, obscuring backend infrastructure is just a defense-in-depth measure, and in no way constitutes sufficient security to prevent a determined assailant.

Answer (score 0):

on most webservers ".html" files will not get parsed with the php interpreter. so i think, yes, there is an speed advantage.

i use .html files for very small sites, without anything special, shure, why not. the will never get updated so there is no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course...if u have static site u know that u wont have PHP code.
i guess that for .php files the server has to parse the file even if it doesnt contain any php tags or code, but i think that its really negligible...

Answer (score 0):

For sure, the main topic's answer is that if you don't need anything in PHP for your site, you can use *.html/*.htm in the index page - as everybody stated.

But sometimes, I use it as a awesome trick: when I want to update some webpages or I want to fix some issue within the site or even say something for the visitors, I do an upload of an index.html page saying what I want. Note that, in this case, You will need to always use index.php for the site itself - *the trick will work for sure*.

Of course, your server need to accept PHP files :P

I hope I helped!